# Etherscan Verifying Contract Code: Error! Constructor arguments provided but might be unncessary because source code contains a public constructor

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan, contract-verification

I'm trying to verify my solidity code through etherscan but it gave me this

> Error! Constructor arguments provided but might be unncessary because
>   source code contains a public constructor. Tip: Try removing the
>   constructor arguments and resubmit.

I deployed the contract to mainnet using truffle via infura. I am passing an address to the constructor and pretty sure the argument is the correct one.

Why does this happen? Why should I remove the constructor arguments?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of exactly what you're inputting and the error message? The message doesn't make sense to me, but perhaps something else will stand out.

Comment: Please share your contract code and the text that you enter in the `constructorArguements` edit-box on Etherscan.